# c shared memory attach/detach/deallocate

Tags: c, client, posix, shared-memory

I have question regarding shared memory segmentation in c using POSIX system calls. Is it right that I am detaching and removing segment from client and server or i just need to remove from server?

Consider I have 2 programmes

One for server and one for client

```
the steps for the server

1)create memory segment
2)attach
3)detach
4)remove

steps for the client

1)create
2)attach
3)detach
4)remove
```

this is my code:

```
//server

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>

#define SHMSZ 100
int main()
{

key_t key;
char c;
int shmid;
char *shm;

key=1025;

//locate
if((shmid=shmget(key,SHMSZ,0666 | IPC_CREAT))<0)
{
perror("shmget");
exit(-1);
}



//attach
if((shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0))==(char*)-1)
{
perror("shmat");
exit(-1);
}


sprintf(shm,"Hi there");

//shm="Hi There";

while(*shm!='*');
sleep(1);

//detach
shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
return 0;
}
```

this is client side

```
//client

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>

#define SHMSZ 100

int main()
{


key_t key;
int shmid;
char c;
char *shm, *s;

key=1025;
//locate
if((shmid=shmget(key,SHMSZ,0666 | IPC_CREAT))<0)
{
perror("shmget");
exit(-1);
}

//attach
if((shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0))==(char*)-1)
{
perror("shmat");
exit(-1);
}

printf("%s\n",shm);

*shm='*';

shmdt(&shmid);
shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using System V IPC rather than POSIX IPC, check the value of `shm_nattch` in the data-structure associated with the ID of the shared memory segment.  You can get this value by calling `shmctl` with a flag of `IPC_STAT`.  Calling `shmdt` will reduce this value by one, and the last process to call this function will set the value of `shm_nattach` to `0`.  Once the value is zeroed-out, you can safely make a call to `shmctl` to remove the memory segment.

So in both your client and server code if the server is not guaranteed to outlive a client, you should check the value of `shm_nattch` with a separate call to `shmctl` after calling `shmdt` to see if the number of processes accessing the shared memory segment has been reduced to zero.  You should also make sure to error-check the results of this `IPC_STAT` call in order to avoid a race-condition where two separate processes call `shmdt`, reducing the value of `shm_nattch` to zero, but the process that was actually the last to call `shmdt` is suspended by the OS, and the other process sees the value of `shm_nattch` is zero and removes the memory segment.  Since both checking and removing the shared memory segment requires calls to `shm_ctl`, and that call will fail if the ID of the shared-memory segment is invalid, you theoretically shouldn't run into any race-conditions if you *only* make calls to `shm_ctl` or `shmdt` after a single process has removed the shared memory segment.  The thing you want to avoid though would be accessing a pointer to the shared memory segment after it's been removed.  Checking for failed calls to `shm_ctl` will help you avoid those types of situations.  In other words if the call fails, then you can't safely access the pointer anymore.

If on the other-hand your server is guaranteed to outlive any of the clients, then the server can safely make the call to remove the shared memory segment, since it will be the last process using it ... all of the other clients will not need to remove the memory segment, but simply detach from it.

Comment: thanks for clarification,
you mean shmctl(shmid,IPC_STAT,NULL) in my case?

Comment: Don't pass `NULL` as the third argument ... you'll need to pass the address of a local `struct shmid_ds` type that you can then use to check the value of `shm_nattch`.

Comment: is it something like that
int ret;
ret=shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, (struct shmid_ds*)&shmid);
if(ret)
{
fprintf(stderr,"error");
}

Comment: Don't cast your ID value as a `shmid_ds` structure ... they're not the same thing at all.  Also you can access the type of error using either `perror()` or `strerror(errno)`, and include `errno.h` and/or `string.h` in your code module if you decide you want to use `strerror()`.  So for instance, you could do `fprintf(stderr, "%s", strerror(errno));` if you call to `shm_ctl` returns `-1`.